# Got "KeyError: <flask.cli.ScriptInfo object at 0x0000000003C05B70>" when running "flask db init"

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

New to python here. Working on a basic project using PyCharm Community edition from [CRUD-PythonFlask](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-crud-web-app-with-python-and-flask-part-one) the site. While performing migration steps got errors as below after the command `flask db init`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 174, in_run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "C:\Users\elkkanah\PycharmProjects\aquauk\venv\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <m
odule>
File "c:\users\elkkanah\pycharmprojects\aquauk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 894, in
main
cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
File "c:\users\elkkanah\pycharmprojects\aquauk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 557, in
main
return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\users\elkkanah\pycharmprojects\aquauk\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 717, i
n main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "c:\users\elkkanah\pycharmprojects\aquauk\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1137,
in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
File "c:\users\elkkanah\pycharmprojects\aquauk\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1137,
in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
File "c:\users\elkkanah\pycharmprojects\aquauk\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 956, i
n invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "c:\users\elkkanah\pycharmprojects\aquauk\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 555, i
n invoke
return callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\users\elkkanah\pycharmprojects\aquauk\venv\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line
17, in new_func
return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
File "c:\users\elkkanah\pycharmprojects\aquauk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 411, in
decorator
with __ctx.ensure_object(ScriptInfo).load_app().app_context():
File "c:\users\elkkanah\pycharmprojects\aquauk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 377, in
load_app
raise_if_not_found=False)
File "c:\users\elkkanah\pycharmprojects\aquauk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 254, in
locate_app
return find_best_app(script_info, module)
File "c:\users\elkkanah\pycharmprojects\aquauk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 76, in
find_best_app
app = call_factory(script_info, app_factory)
File "c:\users\elkkanah\pycharmprojects\aquauk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 114, in
call_factory
return app_factory(script_info)
File "C:\Users\elkkanah\PycharmProjects\aquauk\app\__init__.py", line 19, in create_app
app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
KeyError: <flask.cli.ScriptInfo object at 0x0000000003C05B70>
```

`__init__.py` file:

```
# app/__init__.py

# third-party imports
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_migrate import Migrate

 # local imports
 from config import app_config

 # db variable initialization
 db = SQLAlchemy()
 login_manager = LoginManager()


 def create_app(config_name):
     app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
     app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
     app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
     db.init_app(app)

     login_manager.init_app(app)
     login_manager.login_message = "You must be logged in to access this page."
     login_manager.login_view = "auth.login"

     migrate = Migrate(app, db)

     from app import models

     # temporary route
     @app.route('/')
     def hello_world():
         return 'Hello, World!'

     return app
```

Need help in sorting the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/issues/196#issuecomment-394461486 ?

Comment: thanks @RajaSimon!! It helped!

Comment: Please create a new answer here for future users.

Comment: Cross check and make sure your main script is in the appropriate directory (normally the same level with the app folder). Then cd to the directory with the main script file and run:                                                                                                                        `$ export FLASK_APP=<yourfile.py>`

Answer (score 11):

I have experienced this when using a python file for the FLASK_APP environment variable, rather than using a module (or app in flask terminology), ie:

```
$ export FLASK_APP=flask_app.py
```

instead of

```
$ export FLASK_APP=flask_app:app
```

I think you may be missing the FLASK_APP entirely though, with flask db init exhibiting that behaviour.

Comment: I was having the same problem and this solved it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Remove ## app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name]) line from your code and it will start working..

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the issue lies with the initialization of the db variable. Ensure that your virtual environment is inside the your flask project folder

Answer (score 0):

Your pycharm editor sets the target to flask.py, maybe yours is not flask.py or maybe other, but it won't be __init__.py

Answer (score 0):

if your app_config and config_name if right,this is usually because you did not configure the environment variable FLASK_APP correctly.
How does your runpy.py file call your function create_app()?
if it likes:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = create_app('DEVELOPMENT')

  @app.shell_context_processor
  def make_shell_context():
      return dict(db=db, User=User, Role=Role)

  migrate = Migrate(app, db)
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=50001)
```

just modify it as follows:

```
app = create_app('DEVELOPMENT')

@app.shell_context_processor
def make_shell_context():
    return dict(db=db, User=User, Role=Role)

migrate = Migrate(app, db)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=50001)
```

Also,if there are more than one flask app in your runpy.py,you can select which one you want use in flask shell when configure the environment variable:

```
export FLASK_APP=runpy.py:app1
```